# How to filter Sharepoint List Items Queried with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the .net SDK.  Trying to filter a large list with Microsoft Graph,

My query works fine using .`Items.Request().Expand("fields").GetAsync();`
However, if I add a filter, it doesn't work as expected.

I have tried two approaches :

1. Add `.Expand("fields").Filter("fields/Archived eq false").GetAsync();`  That works, but returns all the list items without filtering.
2. Add `.Expand("fields($filter=Archived eq false)").GetAsync();`
   This does not work - it gives me an error that expand, select, and filter are the only allowed queries.

What does work is `("fields($select=Archived)")`, but of course, no filtering is done.

So how are we to query large lists using Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote the value you pass into your filter: `Fields/Archived eq 'false'` (note the `'`s):

```cs
var result = graphClient
    .Sites["root"]
    .SiteWithPath("siteId")
    .Lists["listId"]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .Expand("Fields")
    .Filter("Fields/Archived eq 'false'");
```

Answer (score 1):

After too much research on this issue i found below solution and its working fine for me:

To Filter you need to add Header parameter as follow:
Prefer : HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

And Graph api will be as follow:
&$filter = Fields/Archived  eq False

Comment: Alternatively you can add the column in SharePoint as an index, this will improve performance rather than filtering against an un-indexed column
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0